# When I load the page, the page displays all the contents. I want it to display content of item1

Tags: jquery

```
//isotope filter
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var $container = $('.isotope-filter');

        $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.single-isotope-filter'
        });

        //relayout 
        setInterval(function(){
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        }, 0);
        //reLayout


        var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
          $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

        $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[ key ] = value;
        if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope( options );
        }

        return false;
        });

    });
    //end isotope filter
```

Content of first tab

```
<div class="single-isotope-filter filterone">content</div>
```

Content of second tab

```
<div class="single-isotope-filter filtertwo">content</div>
```

Content of third tab

```
<div class="single-isotope-filter filterthree">content</div>
```

When I load the page all three contents are displayed. I want it to display just item1 content when i load the page. Can anyone help.

Comment: have you tried working with visibilities

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines is what you're looking for? You can just throw this right under the $(document).ready() function. (non-JQuery version)

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('single-isotope-filter');
for (var i=1; i<divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Or just simply set the visibility with CSS:

```
div.filtertwo,div.filterthree {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Among these methods, there are all kinds of ways you can do this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your method and the content is hidden but if I click the other tabs, they wont display their respective content. Here is the reference link http://swarooha.amzycreations.com/rent.html